# Mongoid3/Moped: database=admin command={:ismaster=>1}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, moped, database

I've upgraded my Rails app to 3.2.8 and Mongoid 3/Moped. Everything works fine in development, on my development machine while set to production, and `rails c` works fine on my production setup as well. However, the app doesn't start (deployed on passenger) and seems to just time out, not producing any errors. I set log_level to debug in production, and this is what I see:

```
Creating scope :near. Overwriting existing method City.near.
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} (5.8458ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} (8.2316ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} (16.2363ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} (13.0076ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} (1.5557ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} (1.5068ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} (1.5004ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} (1.7371ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} (1.7002ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} (2.8868ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} (1.8172ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} (3.0932ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} (10.4055ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} (1.5655ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} (1.4858ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} (1.6346ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} (1.4541ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} (1.5333ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} (1.8239ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} (1.5938ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} (1.4448ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} (1.4253ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} (9.8593ms)
# ... this just carries on indefinitely.
```

How do I fix this? (For the record, the database I'm trying to use is not called admin.)

Thanks,

Avishai

Answer (score 1):

Well, looks like Passenger was in fact running on an old ruby 1.9.2 installation. Updated Passenger to ruby 1.9.3, recompiled nginx, and then it worked fine again.